# Portable one-byte per line hex dump

Tags: portability, hexdump, od

Suppose we want a minimalist one-byte per line *ASCII* hex dump.  Under *Linux* using *GNU* `od`, this works:

```
echo foo | od -An -tx1 -w1 -v
```

Output:

```
 66
 6f
 6f
 0a
```

But that won't work with *BSD* derivatives, because the *BSD* `od` util has different flags.

What's the most portable **nix* method?  Failing that, what are the best available methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`od` is a standard command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html). In `od -An -tx1 -w1 -v`, the only thing that is not POSIX is the `-w` option.

You can replace it with:

```
od -An -vtx1 | LC_ALL=C tr -cs '0-9a-fA-F' '[\n*]' | grep .
```

Which would work in any POSIX-compliant system and does work on FreeBSD at least:

```
$ echo test | od -An -vtx1 | LC_ALL=C tr -cs 0-9a-fA-F '[\n*]' | grep .
74
65
73
74
0a
```

Or with one `sed` invocation to replace the `tr`+`grep`:

```
od -An -vtx1 | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//;/./!d
s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/\
/g'
```

(or

```
od -An -vtx1 | sed -n 's/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]\{2\}\)[[:blank:]]*/\1\
/g;s/\n$//p'
```

)

With `perl` (not a POSIX command but ubiquitous on anything but embedded systems):

```
perl -ne '
  BEGIN{$/ = \8192; $, = $\ = "\n"}
  print  unpack "(H2)*", $_'
```

Which is also the fastest of the 3 in my tests (compared to GNU `od`) by a significant margin for anything but small files (also than `hexdump`, not than `vim`'s `xxd`).

Comment: Useful, but _post_-`od` it needs two pipes.  Would you know if this one-pipe version: `od -An -tx1 | grep -o '[^ ].'` is as portable?

Comment: @agc, `grep -o` is a GNU extension. BSDs `grep` is based on GNU grep (now rewritten) but other Unix-likes generally don't have it. It should be doable with one `sed` instead of `tr+grep`.

Comment: Works on Linux, `od -An -vtx1 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\(..\)/\1\n/g;s/.$//'`, don't know about elsewhere...

Comment: @agc, `\n` on the right-hand side of a `s` command is not POSIX and not portable. The amount of blanks between numbers is also unspecified (typically that command won't work at all on FreeBSD). I can see that Solaris `od` adds an extra blank line at the end, and FreeBSD adds extra spaces at the end of each line so I also need to adapt my sed version.

Comment: A simpler and more readable approach: `od -An -vtx1 |xargs printf '%s\n'`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `hexdump`:

```
$ echo foo | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"'
66
6f
6f
0a
```

Which is original from BSD [its manual is here (in BSD)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hexdump&sektion=1).

However the example shown above was run in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

`xxd` exists in Linux, [BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xxd&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html), and [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xxd.1.html):

```
echo foo | xxd -p -c 1
66
6f
6f
0a
```